# How would one find the item of a List<string> based on it's index

Tags: c#, collections

I would like to display text that is stored in my list.
I have the index number, and would like to use the index number to get the item from the collection.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx):

```
var item = list.ElementAt(3);
```

Or simply use the indexer, like:

```
var item = list[3];
```

Comment: Why use `ElementAt` when `List<T>` has an indexer?

Comment: Personally, i think ElementAt is more readable, but i added an example of using the indexer as well.

Comment: @alexn: Are you a Java programmer at heart, by any chance? ;) (One of the *lovely* things about C# and .NET IMO is the ability to express indexers and properties...)

Comment: @Jon god no. Actually, i dont like Java at all. I just like fluent, readable interfaces. :)

Comment: @alexn: And yet ironically `list.elementAt(3)` would be idiomatic Java, but `list[3]` would be the idiomatic C#, IMO. `ElementAt` is great when you've only got an `IEnumerable<T>`, but when you know you've got an indexer, you might as well use it :)

Answer (score 5):

If it's a `List<string>`, why not just use:

```
string item = list[index];
```

?

Comment: Thx for answering so quickly! I will repose my question, because I don't understand your answer. I feel i might not have expressed myself well. My list has 6 entries, I selected a cell which represents the 5th entry. Now I would like to display the text that is associated with that entry. Again thx in adavnce

Comment: From your discussion w/ alaxn, you did understand my question. Could you elaborate on your answer so i can better understand your method?

Comment: @Yaron: I'm not sure what there is to elaborate on... `List<T>` has an indexer, which lets you use the `foo[index]` syntax to access an element at a particular index. What else do you need to know?

Comment: What to look up to better understand your answer. You provided it foo[index].  Again thx

Comment: @Yaron: The docs for the indexer are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346281.aspx - but if you're new to C#, I suggest you find a good introductory book rather than trying to learn in an ad hoc manner.